# sql select into select in function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

When I try to alter the function below I get the following error message:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I guess it is probably because of select into select. But why does this select into select work separately ( not in function ) but not in function.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Getcurrentexchangerate] (@CurrencyFromId INT, 
                                               @CurrencyToId   INT) 
returns DECIMAL(13, 10) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @rate DECIMAL (13, 10) 
      DECLARE @dw INT 

      SET @dw = (SELECT Datepart(dw, Getdate())) 

      IF( @dw != 2 ) -- Monday       
        BEGIN 
            SET @rate = (SELECT TOP (1) [rate] 
                         FROM   currencyconversionrate 
                         WHERE  [currencyfromid] = @CurrencyFromId 
                                AND [currencytoid] = @CurrencyToId 
                         ORDER  BY id DESC) 
        END 
      ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            SET @rate = (SELECT * 
                         FROM   (SELECT TOP(2) Row_number() 
                                                 OVER ( 
                                                   ORDER BY id DESC) AS 
                                               rownumber, 
                                               rate 
                                 FROM   currencyconversionrate 
                                 WHERE  ( [currencyfromid] = 2 
                                          AND [currencytoid] = 5 ) 
                                 ORDER  BY id DESC) AS Rate 
                         WHERE  rownumber = 2) 
        END 

      IF( @rate IS NULL ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @rate = 1 
        END 

      RETURN @rate 
  END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your "else" part

```
 SET @rate = (SELECT * 
                         FROM   (SELECT TOP(2) Row_number() 
                                                 OVER ( 
                                                   ORDER BY id DESC) AS 
                                               rownumber, 
                                               rate 
                                 FROM   currencyconversionrate 
                                 WHERE  ( [currencyfromid] = 2 
                                          AND [currencytoid] = 5 ) 
                                 ORDER  BY id DESC) AS Rate 
                         WHERE  rownumber = 2)
```

You're trying to select all fields from currencyconversionrate table, you can't do that, or do you want to select "RATE" column only?

Try changing to below:

```
 SET @rate = (SELECT rate
                         FROM   (SELECT TOP(1) Row_number() 
                                                 OVER ( 
                                                   ORDER BY id DESC) AS 
                                               rownumber, 
                                               rate 
                                 FROM   currencyconversionrate 
                                 WHERE  ( [currencyfromid] = 2 
                                          AND [currencytoid] = 5 ) 
                                 ORDER  BY id DESC) AS Rate 
                         WHERE  rownumber = 2)
```